# Extra background appears at Win 10 login... What to do?

Tags: windows-10, troubleshooting, login-screen, hijack

I wonder what cause this extra background at login...

Suddenly it just came, and now it seems to be their everytime. Even after making a clean re-install of OS.

I'm worried I might be hacked or something like that... Cause my PC has been acting a bit strange after this began, things like volume adjusting by itself a bunch of times.

I hope one of you guys can tell me how to fix it or how to go even deeper into looking for hidden user activity etc.

FYI I run my setup with a single monitor and a normal background setup on Win 10 Home.

See the extra background at the left side

[image: See the extra background at the left side]

Comment: **You are absolutely not being hacked.** It just appears that the image is being tiled for some reason.

Comment: This particular image is simply broken. It looked the same on my PC when I had it.